# Is there a way to define multi-field index without index_together Meta option?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-1.4

I am working on a legacy django project that uses django 1.4.
For a new model I tried to add a multi-field index with:

```
class Meta:
     index_together = [
         ["user","is_read"],
     ]
```

It turns out `index_together` is not supported yet in django 1.4.

My question is, without using `index_together` feature, is there any way in django ORM to define a multi-field index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't an alternative to `index_together` in Django 1.4.

However, you can write raw SQL to create the index. If you include it in your [initial sql data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-sql-data), Django will run it after creating the tables.

If you have already created the tables, you can open up a db shell and run the SQL command to create the index.